# Unsupported Media Format 'video/mpeg-1', url='null'

Tags: java, java-me

I'm trying to show a video on the java ME 3.5 sdk emulator but I keep getting Unsupported Media Format 'video/mpeg-1', url='null' exception.
I also tried to change `'video/mpeg-1'` to `'video/mpeg'` but it still doesn't work. However it works fine when I lunch it on Wireless toolkit 2.5 emulator !

```
   public void startApp() {
    try {
        if (error) {
            return;
        }
        //display.setCurrent(list);
        loadPlayer();
        VideoControl videoControl = (VideoControl) player.getControl("javax.microedition.media.control.VideoControl");
        if (videoControl == null) {
            throw new Exception("No VideoControl!!");
        }
        videoControl.initDisplayMode(VideoControl.USE_DIRECT_VIDEO, canvas);
        videoControl.setDisplayFullScreen(true);
        videoControl.setVisible(true);
        display.setCurrent(canvas);
        player.start();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void loadPlayer() throws Exception {
    player = Manager.createPlayer(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/1.mpg"), "video/mpeg-1");
    player.realize();
}
```

Comment: J2ME will only play the video formats supported by the actual device. Very few devices supports mpeg, which is probably why your emulator won't play it either. Trying converting your video to 3gp or mp4.

Comment: I've tried 3gp too but still not working

Comment: Just to be sure... Add InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/1.mpg"); and check that this is not null.